# Newly added element with multiple div's using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, dynamic, element

Why I cannot get the `text` of this newly added multiple child div's. I'm using JQuery to add this dynamic elements. here my sample fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qx1qao6y/2/)

Can someone explain to me where did I go wrong?

**Script**

```
var counter = 0;

$("button").click(function() {

$("<div class='child-list-workorder'>\
                            <div class='list-workorder'>\
                               <div class='list-workorder-header'>\
                                 <h3 id='" + counter + "' class='list-workorder-id'>click me " + (++counter) + "</h3>\
                               </div>\
                               <p>" + counter + "</p>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>").appendTo("div.parent-list-workorder");

    });


$("div.list-workorder-header").on("click", "h3.list-workorder-id", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: you are not using event delegation properly - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qx1qao6y/3/

Comment: the event handler should be bound to a static element, in this case `.parent-list-workorder`

Comment: please post the code also as part of your question, not just the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**delegated event**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as html is generated dynamically:

```
$(document).on("click", "h3.list-workorder-id", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

your div with class **child-list-workorder** is also generated dynamically so :

```
$(".child-list-workorder").on("click", "h3.list-workorder-id", function(){
...............
```

will not work as it is also generated dynamically.

or you can use parent div which has class **parent-list-workorder**  that is loaded on DOM load:

```
$(".parent-list-workorder").on("click", "h3.list-workorder-id", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**WORKING UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qx1qao6y/5/)

Comment: Thanks mate! it works! but how about I change my `.on SELECTOR` to one of my Class DIV which is `.list-workorder` then I want to alert the value of my `<h3>`? please see my updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qx1qao6y/7/)

Comment: @Unknownymous2 use ``find()`` see :http://jsfiddle.net/qx1qao6y/8/